# Is "I am still taking fun of it" correct usage?

Tags: grammar

Is

> I am still taking fun of it

correct usage? I want to mean that it is still funny to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am still taking fun of it* is fairly non-sensical. Try *I still find it funny* or *it's still funny to me*.

Answer (score 6):

> I am still taking fun of it

is incorrect usage, as the phrase *take fun of* does not exist in standard English. Perhaps, you want to say

> I am still making fun of it

*Make fun of* is a standard phrase which means:

> tease, laugh at, or joke about (someone) in a mocking or unkind way. <sup>[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1249505#m_en_us1249505)</sup>

However, this may not be quite you mean. In that case, you could simply say:

> I am still finding it funny / I still find it funny

I should add that *I am still finding it funny* is a construction a native speaker would likely never or rarely use. Thus, *I still find it funny* is the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not standard, and I've never even come across this as a non-standard form. *I am still amused by it*, or *I still find it funny* are valid ways of expressing this.